# how to save a select item in django

Tags: python, django

how to save a select item with a background color in a django of a display list of listed project items i was trying to use javascript queryselectors but it kept on selecting the frist project item with a green background indicating the project was taken, i wanted it done but clicking on a particular project id changing it background to green as indication that project has already been. am open to suggestions dont know what am doing wrong

```
{% if latest_question_list %}

  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row example" id="posted-projects">

        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <img src="{% static 'img\profile.png' %}" width="60"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <br>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</a>
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <br>
          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <br>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Take Project</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <br>
          <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'explore:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
          <br>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% else %}
  <p>No project are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I've updated the code indentation and formatting in the question, but please try and look over how the code is visualised next time.

Comment: Where do you want to save it?